# WordPress Custom Post Type permalink question

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have a custom post type called Auction House.  How can I get the permalink to be sitename.com/selling/auction_houses?ah=House1 ?

I need the single URL of all Auction Houses to go to the same URL (sitename.com/selling/auction_houses) but with a custom query string parameter on the end for a single auction house URL. The query string parameter can be used to allow me to pick up and make scroll to the correct auction house on the page.

Thanks,
Neil

EDIT 1:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_auction_house() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Auction Houses.
     */

    $labels = [
        "name" => __( "Auction Houses", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Auction House", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __( "Auction Houses", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "rest_namespace" => "wp/v2",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "can_export" => true,
        "rewrite" => [ "slug" => "auction_house", "with_front" => true ],
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-store",
        "supports" => [ "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ],
        "show_in_graphql" => false,
    ];

    register_post_type( "auction_house", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_auction_house' );
```

Comment: Please share code snippet of your custom post type creation

Comment: @suraj-wasnik I am using CPTUI in order to add the CPT, but I have exported the code and added to my OP.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to change this line `"rewrite" => [ "slug" => "auction_house", "with_front" => true ],`  to `"rewrite" => [ "slug" => "houses", "with_front" => true ],` Cheers!

Comment: @SurajWasnik Thanks, I think I may have confused the situation slightly. I've updated my OP to try to explain what I am after more clearly.  Does that help at all?

Comment: @rctneil for clarification, would there ever be an instance of someone viewing the single page for an auction house? It seems to me that if you just want to have a URL with query parameters to auto-scroll on the archive page you just need to have the place you link to the archive page with an auction house formatted the way you want, then handle the scroll that way. I'm not sure where the need to alter the permalink behavior arises.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things you need to modify from the original code, as well as a function to add to redirect from the single page to the archive with the query parameters. One thing to note is that users will not be able to get to the single page because it is getting redirected.

Add the following to the `$args` of the custom part type:

```
"has_archive" => 'selling/auction_houses',
```

Modify this in the $args of the custom post type:
Change this:

```
"rewrite" => [ "slug" => "auction_house", "with_front" => true ],
```

to this:

```
"rewrite" => ["slug" => "selling/auction_houses", "with_front" => true],
```

Lastly add this function to handle the redirect from the single page to the archive page with query parameters.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'AH_auction_house_single_redirect');

function AH_auction_house_single_redirect()
{
  if (is_singular('auction_house')) {
    global $wp;
    // Get the slug of the post for url
    $slug = end(explode('/', add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request)));

    /**
     * 
     * Select whether you want to use 301 or 307 as your redirect
     * 
     */
    
    // wp_redirect( home_url() . '/selling/auction_houses?ah=' . $slug, 301 );
    wp_redirect(home_url() . '/selling/auction_houses?ah=' . $slug, 307);
    exit;
  }
}
```

That will make the new code in it's entirety look like this:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_auction_house()
{

  /**
   * Post Type: Auction Houses.
   */

  $labels = [
    "name" => __("Auction Houses", "custom-post-type-ui"),
    "singular_name" => __("Auction House", "custom-post-type-ui"),
  ];

  $args = [
    "label" => __("Auction Houses", "custom-post-type-ui"),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "rest_namespace" => "wp/v2",
    "has_archive" => 'selling/auction_houses',
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "can_export" => true,
    "rewrite" => ["slug" => "selling/auction_houses", "with_front" => true],
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-store",
    "supports" => ["title", "editor", "thumbnail"],
    "show_in_graphql" => false,
  ];

  register_post_type("auction_house", $args);
}

add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_auction_house');

add_action('template_redirect', 'AH_auction_house_single_redirect');

function AH_auction_house_single_redirect()
{
  if (is_singular('auction_house')) {
    global $wp;
    // Get the slug of the post for url
    $slug = end(explode('/', add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request)));

    /**
     * 
     * Select whether you want to use 301 or 307 as your redirect
     * 
     */
    
    // wp_redirect( home_url() . '/selling/auction_houses?ah=' . $slug, 301 );
    wp_redirect(home_url() . '/selling/auction_houses?ah=' . $slug, 307);
    exit;
  }
}
```